# Cannot view the collections I created on my kindle touch

Tags: kindle, ebook-management, collections

I was recently given a kindle touch. I have created 3 collections, and have added several books to each. But when I go to the dropdown to sort the view, "Collections" is greyed out inactive. Did the same on amazon webpage - still cannot see the collections on my kindle. Tried clicking "sync and check for items" - it just says there are no new items. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

New collections were not implemented on K4. Collections which you can create on  K4 were created only on the local device. They won't go on the cloud.

According to the [Amazon site](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201715640), QUOTE: "Cloud Collections are currently supported on 6th Generation and newer Kindle e-readers, and 3rd Generation and newer Fire tablets." (and also, Kindle apps on Android/ios devices)

Finally, a tip from someone who uses collections often, you should organize your collections via the Manage your Content and Devices interface. (This is especially true if you are on an e-ink device). It's much easier.

Comment: Thank you so much @idiotprogrammer! That answers one problem. However, the original problem was when I tried collections on the device itself. The UI exists to do it, I can go through the actions of creating collections and adding books to the collection. The UI also exists to view by collections - the dropdown gives options to view by Recent, Title, Author, and Collections. But - and this is the real question - the Collections option is greyed out. Given the fact that the UI exists, why can I not actually view by collections? Thanks for any more help you or anyone can offer!

Comment: When DEVICE is selected on Home screen,  the top right menu has an option for  Create New Collection should work. Try to create a collection and then add ebooks from there. Perhaps it is greyed out only because you haven't created any local collections.

Comment: Thanks. No, that's exactly what I've done. It hasn't worked. THanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that  when at first menu "All Items" is selected , not Books. Collections should then be available.